# Typescript- Add dynamic fields in filter

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I add n number of fields dynamically in filter?? I would like to pass 1 field or 2 fields or n fields based on my requirements..

```
myArray.filter(x => x.field1 === field1Value && x.field2 === field2Value &&  so on depending on my requirements..);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way can be

```
let attrValues = [{attr:'name', value:'Marcus'}, { attr:'age', value=24}]
    
    myArray.filter(x=>{
    return attrValues.every(item=>x[item.attr] == item.value)
    })
```

Comment: Maybe you should suggest [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of `forEach()`

Comment: That worked.. Thanks a lot.. Small correction: it's item.value at last not attr.value...!!!